# Cosine similarity of list of values with each other

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to find the cosine similarity of a list of strings. I used sklearn tfidf vector to convert the text into a numerical vector first and then used the pairwise cosine_similarity api to find the score for each string pair.

The strings seem similar, but I am getting a weird answer. The first and third value in the string array are similar except the word TRENTON, but the cosine similarity is 0. Similarly, the 1st,3rd and 4th string are the same, except for a space between GREEN and CHILLI and the cosine similarity is zero. Isn't that strange?

My code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_kernels
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer()

values =['GREENCHILLI TRENTON'
,'GREENCHILLI'
,'GREEN CHILLI'
,'GREEN CHILLI']

X_train_counts = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(values)
similarities = cosine_similarity(X_train_counts) 
print(similarities)
```

**Output**

```
 [[1.        0.6191303 0.        0.       ]
 [0.6191303 1.        0.        0.       ]
 [0.        0.        1.        1.       ]
 [0.        0.        1.        1.       ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

coma (,) missing between last two GREEN CHILLI so tfidf is treating them as only 3 records not 4.

If you correct it you should see below cosine similarity

`[[1.        0.6191303 0.        0.       ]
 [0.6191303 1.        0.        0.       ]
 [0.        0.        1.        1.       ]
 [0.        0.        1.        1.       ]]`

How to interpret the above matrix: The value in the nth row are cosine similarities of that tfidf vector with all other vectors (in sequential order). So all the diagonal will be 1 because every vector is similar to itself.

Answer (score 0):

> The first and third value in the string array values is similar except the word Trenton but cosine similarity is 0. 
>   Similarly, 1st,3rd and 4th strings are same only space between GREEN and CHILLI and the cosine similarity is zero. isn't it strange?

It is not as strange as you might think. You will only get a non-zero cosine similarity if you have exact word matches between the strings that you compare. I will try to explain what happens:

When the TF-IDF vectorizer creates vectors from your list of strings, it starts by making a list of all words that occur.

So in your case, the list would look like this:

`GREENCHILLI
TRENTON
GREEN
CHILLI`

Now, every word becomes an axis in a coordinate system that the algorithm uses. All axes are **perpendicular** to each other.

So when you compare 'GREENCHILLI TRENTON' with 'GREEN CHILLI', the algorithm makes two vectors. One from 'GREENCHILLI TRENTON' that has a component parallel to 'GREENCHILLI' and a component parallel to 'TRENTON'. The vector from the string 'GREEN CHILI' has components in 'GREEN' and 'CHILLI' direction of your coordinate system. When you calculate the dot product between the two you will get a zero. So the cosine similarity is zero as well.

So the gap in 'GREEN CHILLI' makes all the difference, when you compare it to 'GREENCHILLI'. The letters don't matter anymore, once the vectorizer made its coordinate system based on all the words it found in your list, because it identifies 'GREENCHILLI', 'GREEN' and 'CHILLI' as different words and makes them into perpendicular axes in its reference coordinate system.

Hope that makes it more clear. I suggest reading the following article series for a more in-depth understanding of whats going on:

http://blog.christianperone.com/2011/09/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-i/